# Postgres subtract decimals returning unexpected result

Tags: postgresql

I'm doing some calculation in queries on numbers in portgres and it's returning a weird result, I suspect it's due to how decimals / floats work in general, but I need a way to solve it, given:

```
SELECT 1.2627107407 - 1.2627107407 as test --same numbers for both values
```

The answer should be 0, but instead it returns `0E-10`.

What is a good way of fixing this?

Comment: What client are you using? Are you seeing `0E-10` in the client or somewhere else?

Comment: Interesting...when I try the same (v 13, psql and DBeaver), I get `0.0000000000`, because the numbers are implicitly cast to `numeric`, which is an _exact_ data type.  I would only expect scientific notation from an _inexact_ datatype such as `real` or `double precision`.  What PG version and what query tool are you using?

Comment: PG 13.1 / Omnidb